# Please post questions!

Tags: discussion

I can post <strike>six</strike> unlimited questions a day, and so can you.  Please try to post as many good questions as you can think of each and every day.  The site activity will only increase if people know that there's new content every hour.

I'm planning on posting at least six questions a day, and only answering them myself if they don't get any answers by the next day.

It can be difficult, but I think this site is needed, and I don't want to see it die.  Just post as many questions as you can every day, and I suspect activity will go up.

Comment: Alright, we've kicked December 2nd off the front page.  Now we need to get December 3rd off the front page...

Comment: Trying hard as well, every question I come up with has generally been asked. Short of going through the exam questions some of us just can't come up with as much.  I assure you some of us are trying though!

Comment: I've asked the powers that be to [change the policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211021/please-increase-the-question-limit-during-beta), so we'll see if that works.  If not, maybe I'll start handing out question ideas that others could ask.  One of my games in the early days of stackoverflow was coming up with an off-the-wall topic, then trying to make a valid programming question out of it...

Comment: Just avoid seeding (and it looks like you are), noting only for general reference. As long as the questions are something someone is very likely to face - great :)

Comment: I try not to be *too* seedy.